# Can I request removal of "too broad" and "needs more focus"?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, multiple-questions, too-broad, focus

Q&A can be conducted at different levels of details. If a question asks about the big picture, an answer should just answer the big picture. The sun is giagantic, but when you see from the Earth, it is "focused". If you use a microscope to look at an ant, the ant is not "focused". Which level of detail is focused and which is not depend on what lens are used, and have already lead to very subjective calls and abuses by some powerful users to suppress posts of others.

So aren't "too broad" and "needs more focus" bad reasons to close posts, and can I request to remove the

Comment: 'Abuses', 'power users' blah..   downvote instead of rude/abusive because I accept that curators are not protected by the terms of service or CoC.

Comment: Yes, they are valid reasons, because they're in the system as valid reasons. Did you mean "valid" in, like, a _moral_ sense?

Comment: The definition is: "**Needs more focus** - Please edit the question to ***limit it to a specific problem*** with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. **Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once**. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.". -- It means "Ask only **one** question" (though sometimes closely related additional questions squeeze through). It has **nothing to do with**: distance, complexity, clairity (that's a different reason), size, or amount of research prior to asking; as is the case here. --- One question, with a few differences in each answer.

Comment: Depends. Can we stop people from asking big picture questions? Then we can abolish the close reason.

Comment: Here's the list of scenarios where "too broad" can be applied: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323603/is-it-possible-for-some-too-broad-questions-to-be-exceptions-to-the-rule/323713#323713 If you want to make a strong argument against it, you should probably carefully consider each one of them. P.S. As you may have noticed, baseless allegations don't help your cause.

Answer (score 10):

I think that the **Needs more focus** (formerly **Too Broad**) close reason is extremely useful when assessing whether a question is asking multiple questions.

A question can be singular, clear and concise, irrespective of whether it is coarse-grained (big picture) or fine-grained but, unless it is very carefully worded, any "big picture" questions typically require multiple questions to be answered, in order to answer them.

I think asking only one question per question is one of the most important skills to be learned by new users of Stack Exchange sites, because it enables focused Q&A to become second nature.

Answer (score -8):

**Are “too broad” and “needs more focus” abolishable?**

Yes but it depends on the site and the community -- i.e. what the community wants or chooses to allow.

And therefore no, it's usually not possible -- i.e. most communities want to use the site for questions with a narrower focus (instead of a broader or wide-angle focus).

One SE community that I know of didn't want many of the usual SE close reasons, wanted instead to accept a wider range of questions.

The policy there is that a broad question is OK, but can't expect much more than only a shallow answer (albeit perhaps with some helpful references, so the OP can read more in-depth).

I think that might be especially useful for complete beginners, who want an overview of the subject matter and don't really know any details to ask about. That kind of conflicts with SE (or SO's) original mission -- i.e. experts or at least practioners answering practical questions -- even so SE's Q&A format and ethos can be helpful (or adapted to be helpful) for beginners too.

It's possible that "broad" questions are beginner's questions, and are actually frequently-asked, and might possibly be refactored sooner or later into FAQs.